# Does the Blink spell break grapples?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, grapple, teleportation

If I am grappling someone while I have the Blink spell activated, does that person travel with me or is the grapple broken?

Answer (score 14):

From the Grappled condition in Appendix A of the Player's Handbook or Player's Basic Rules:

> The condition also ends if an effect removes the 
>   grappled creature from the reach of the grappler or 
>   grappling effect, such as when a creature is hurled 
>   away by the thunderwave spell.

So if you use *Blink* and vanish into the Ethereal Plane, the grapple will end. Obviously if you use *Blink* and **don't** vanish into the Ethereal Plane, the grapple will keep going until you do.

Comment: Also of note.... Blink can get you OUT of a grapple.  Interesting....

Answer (score 12):

**Yes it breaks grapples, no you can not take somebody with you.**

Pertinent part of the *Blink* spell that pertains to your question:

> You can only affect and be affected by other
>   creatures on the Ethereal Plane. Creatures that aren’t
>   there can’t perceive you or interact with you, unless they
>   have the ability to do so.

The spell doesn't say you can take somebody with you. The spell is also specific in that it states **you** move between the planes. It does not indicate an area, or multiple creatures.

Now, if the target you were grappling was able to interact with the etheral plane, or if you were able to interact with the material plane from the ethereal plane, then you could maintain the grapple.

Comment: How far does "you" extend?  Do all your items and armor get dropped?

Comment: Not unless the spell says so. Polymorph for example has a line that says your gear either merges into your form or falls at your feet.

Comment: That clause seems connected to the previous sentence, which says in effect "when on the Ethereal Plane."  When blinking from the Material plane, you aren't on the Ethereal Plane.  (Without this interpretation, when in the Material Plane and under the effect of Blink you could not hit anyone).  It says **you**, nothing about your gear or what you are carrying; if you are carrying another creature, shouldn't that creature come with you as much as your sword would?

Comment: That's a DM ruling at best. There's some precedent for it, like Gwuenhwyvar taking Drizzt to the Astral plane through her figurine's magic. However that is not the spell *blink.* For more information on the Ethereal plane, check the DMG. Ultimately, the spell does not say you can take somebody with you, and does not say your gear is dropped. Since other spells DO emphasize when those effects happen, that they are not specified here is telling.